# Почему GitHub, но Твиттер?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, статус-так-задумано, локализация

Почему везде в строках GitHub остаётся на английском, а Twitter перевели как Твиттер?

К примеру, в настройках профиля:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрится неоднородно. Нужно либо везде английскую версию использовать, либо переводить тогда уж всё.

Comment: Надо было оставить оригинальные английские названия

Comment: @L.F.C. я тоже за оригинальные названия.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для названий внешних ресурсов использованы те названия, которые имеются в русскоязычной **официальной** версии, если такая версия вообще имеется. Для Twitter - это Твиттер, для Facebook - Facebook.

> [image: twitter]

> [image: facebook]

А для GitHub русскоязычной версии вовсе нет, поэтому используется единственная оригинальная.

LinkedIn ещё в копилку из нижнего подвала ruSO:

> [image: linkedin]