# Не переведены строки в новом окне "поделиться ссылкой"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, sharing

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: VK так и не добавили...

Comment: Прежде чем вернёте любимую метку обратно, перечитайте ответ Николая https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9512/199733

Comment: @edem если хотите поменять/синонимизировать метку, создайте новый вопрос. Николай точно такой же участник сообщества. Только лишь его голоса в этом вопросе не достаточно. Вернее, его голос не может быть решающим, т.к. вопросами контента занимается всё сообщество.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13226

> Поделиться ссылкой на вопрос

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13228

> Поделиться ссылкой на ответ

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13231

> (включает ваш идентификатор)

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13230

> Скопировать ссылку

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13223

> Поделиться ссылкой на ответ в $socialNetwork$

Comment: Почему-то про шаринг ещё [не подхватилось](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvdK8.png). А ... на ответ - обновилось, а не вопрос - ещё нет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ага, проморгал изначально. Уже после выкатки добавил перевод.

Comment: Кстати, теперь получается расхождение с [наименованием соц.сетей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8741/176217). Twitter захардкожен. По идее, можно бы баг завести на MSE.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вперёд. Я со своим "деградирующим" русским больше к локализации не притронусь (:

Comment: Почему `включает`, а не `содержит`? // cc @αλεχολυτ

Comment: @Qwertiy там **includes**, а не **contains** в оригинале.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну мне кажется, кривовато по-русски звучит, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy не уверен, мне кажется, по смыслу **включает** лучше подходит. Но вы всегда можете предложить другой вариант ведь (:

Comment: @Qwertiy не только лишь предложить, но и даже утвердить.